# Need to add Item Id in fnd_message in workflow notification in oracle apps

Tags: oracle, function, plsql, procedure, erp

I need to add item id in subject of workflow notification message when item's product life cycle gets error-ed out in oracle apps inventory

Comment: Please add some more informations. Have a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Adding additions to workflows such as this is simple EBS customization.  I believe you should research the following:

You need to determine which workflow is being called:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/workflow.101/b10284/embed.htm

Then you need to know how to customize workflows:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E26401_01/doc.122/e22011/toc.htm